# Add a column to an existing site from a site column

Tags: 2010, development, content

I have a feature that will add 2 columns to site columns. However I need to add them to the list.  Because its an existing development and the didnt start from scratch using feature versioning, I prefer to do the second part by code.

These are my fields

```
<Field ID="{65076B51-5D7C-4140-A5E9-F7D794351489}" Name="BudgetType" DisplayName="$Resources:SPNLSponsoring,Field_BudgetInternalType_Name;" Description="$Resources:SPNLSponsoring,Field_BudgetInternalType_Description;" Group="$Resources:SPNLSponsoring,Field_NationaleLoterijSponsoringColumns_Group;" Type="TaxonomyFieldType" ShowField="Term1033" StaticName="BudgetInternalType" Required="FALSE" Hidden="FALSE" />
  <Field ID="{5E4C6D2A-DA94-4547-80BD-D79C3DD15CB0}" Name="BudgetInternalTypeTaxHTField0" DisplayName="BudgetInternalTypeTaxHTField0;" Description="EventInternalTypeTaxHTField0;" Group="$Resources:SPNLSponsoring,Field_NationaleLoterijSponsoringColumns_Group;" Type="Note" StaticName="EventInternalTypeTaxHTField0" Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" Required="FALSE" />
```

1. How can I add them programatically to the list?
2. How can I modify one view to add one of these columns?

Comment: im not sure what you are asking. what is wrong with having to adding site columns to a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first part is easy, just use the AvailableFields collection fro the SPWeb object like this:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Adds existing site columns to an existing list and then modifies one view to add one of the new site columns
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="web"></param>
        private void AddFieldsAndModifyView(SPWeb web)
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists["Budgets"];
            if (!list.Fields.ContainsField("BudgetInternalType"))
            {
                list.Fields.Add(web.AvailableFields["BudgetInternalType"]);
                list.Update();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a snippet followed by some documention for second part

```
SPList list = web[listname]
SPView view = list.Views[viewname]
view.ViewFields.Add(col1)
view.ViewFields.Add(col2)
view.Update
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spviewfieldcollection_members